# What is the HTML5 itemid attribute and how do you use it?

Tags: html

Can someone give me a couple of examples on how to code the `itemid` attribute for HTML5 as well as what the `itemid` attribute is used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a global identifier for a Microdata [item](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#items).  If you're not using Microdata you shouldn't need `itemid` for anything, if you are using Microdata you should review the many examples in [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#microdata).  If the spec is too dense for you, here's some tutorials:

- [Microdata: HTML5’s Best-Kept Secret](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/09/microdata-html5s-best-kept-secret/)
- [HTML5 Microdata: Welcome to the Machine](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-microdata-welcome-to-the-machine/)
- [Dive into HTML5: Distributed Extensibility](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/extensibility.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also has the same problem. Wherever I read, I found that confusing. 
Here is just one paragraph which is clear with example.
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110405/#global-identifiers-for-items